# PM2 Stopping without Starting

Tags: node.js, angularjs, pm2, dspace

I am trying to install Dspace 7.0 on my Windows Server 2012. I have successfully installed the Backend according to the [documentation](https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSDOC7x/Installing+DSpace)
Now when I am installing the front end, I have installed Nodejs, Yarn, and PM2. also, `yarn run build:prod` seems to be successful.
After I created the below file, **dspace-angular.json**

```js
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "name": "dspace-angular",
            "cwd": "/home/dspace/dspace-angular",
            "script": "yarn",
            "args": "run serve:ssr",
           "interpreter": "none"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to run the below, according to the documentation.
[image]

But,
When I run `pm2 start dspace-angular.json` i get the below screen.

[image]

Right now I have no idea what to do next. Your kind help is highly appreciated.

Comment: in script you specified only yarn and nothing else, is that command to run your app

Comment: Did you try to actually 'run serve:ssr'? What was the result?

Comment: @EzizHudayberdiyev It was on the documentation. Should I CHange it?

Comment: @EstusFlask I just created the JSON and when I ran pm2 start dspace-angular.json I got the above terminal lscreenshot.

Comment: Try changing it cause pm2 seems to be unable to run app. I also had that kind of issue with node application when tried to run in cluster mode

Comment: @EzizHudayberdiyev to what should i change it?

Comment: i changed it to path where server was starting like /dist/app.js

Comment: *yarn run build:prod seems to be successful* - so you tried some script but not the one you're actually running. Isolate the problem by not using PM2 temporarily and running exactly the same thing that PM2 is supposed to run. You're making it harder to solve. I'd expect that the script fails with or without PM2.

Comment: I have the same issue. The problem is with CWD. It seems it doesn't follow the path since windows full path has a colon (:) and (maybe) treated as a new key. I did not have any success in running pm2 in windows even if I escaped the colon and backslash or use a relative path.

Comment: @EstusFlask Hi, After your instructions i ran yarn without pm2. and now um stucked here again. can you please have a look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68811629/dspace-does-not-load